# In CSS ,why am I not able to use font-weight with the em relative unit?

Tags: html, css

According to my knowledge of relative units , the font-weight should be set according to the parent font-size but the property when I am using it with em is not being reflected??

I tried this: ![complete CSS code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8YEo.png)

and this is what I got: ![output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH6Su.png)

complete html code: ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEAEY.png)

Comment: Please provide reproducable example and not images

Comment: Font weight isn't a pixel value, and won't directly map to the font size well, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Font-weight and font-size are actually unrelated properties - why would they be related? Do you want it to automatically make the font bolder when the size is larger? Because that's a _choice_ you can make, not something anyone expects to happen. If you increase the font-size in Word from 12px to 250px, does the font immediately go super bold?

Comment: Font-weight is unitless. Variable fonts support seamless font-weight values e.g from 100-1000 based on a range defined by the designer (not standardized). Static fonts don't. If your `@font-face` rule defines a font with a weight of 400 and you set a weight of 700 via css - the browser will try to find and apply a bolder version. If no bolder version is specified by a separate `@font-face` rule and successfully loaded - the browser will synthetically bolden the rendering to imitate a bold variant (aka "faux-bold"). E.g applying font-weight 900 will fallback to 700 if no " heavy" font is loaded